# Is infinity always a regular value of rational function from $S^1\to S^1$

Tags: differential-topology

$f$ is a rational function $S^1\to S^1$, where $S^1$ is the one point compactification of $\mathbb R$. Is $\infty$ always a regular value of $f$?

Comment: Once you've gone from $\Bbb R$ to $S^1$, does $\infty$ play any special role?